# Strings As Arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

I'm new to c and I was trying to do simple stuff to learn about strings and char arrays, I'm stuck in this section of code.

```
 const char *words(int count) {
  char *words = "words";
  if(count==1) {
    words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';// segmentation fault
  }
  return words;
}
```

what it does is returning word when count equals one and returns words otherwise.
my question is  why is this line of code problematic, why I cant look at string as an array of char's

```
words[strlen(words)-1] = '\0';
```

I tried to declare the string(array of chars ) in a different way like
 `char *words = {'w','o','r','d','s'};`
but I still get  a segmentation fault.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Answer (score 2):

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 N1256
6.7.8 Initialization - 32, EXAMPLE 8 The declaration

> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines ‘‘plain’’ char array objects s and t whose elements are
>   initialized with character string literals. This declaration is
>   identical to
>
> ```
> char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
> t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
> ```
>
> **The contents of the arrays are modifiable**. On the other hand, the declaration
>
> ```
> char *p = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines p with type ‘‘pointer to char’’ and initializes it to point to
>   an object with type ‘‘array of char’’ with length 4 whose elements are
>   initialized with a character **string literal**. **If an attempt is
>   made to use p to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is
>   undefined**.

---

In short, you try to modify the content pointed by `words` which is declared as `char * words = "words"`, and the string literal `"words"` is usually stored in read-only section, that's why you got a SEGSEV.

Comment: "If an attempt is made to use p to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined." i see ...that was the problem but your suggestion is not helping, i want to return the array words, but i cant return words as local variable, the solution is to declare it in the heap bu i dont know any other way than    using apointer, can i use malloc/calloc here? is it necessary?

Comment: Oh I don't notice you want to return an array. Yes malloc is necessary